# Parsing XML to html5-database with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, database, html, sqlite

I am trying to import a XML file into an html5-db like this: (before I `initDatabase` and `createTables`).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", url: "xml/pois_small.xml", dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('sixcms_article').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).find('field[container$="content"]').text();
            var name = $(this).find('title').text();
            var street = $(this).find('field[name$="street"]').text();
            DEMODB.transaction(function (transaction) {
                transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO page(id, name, street) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [id[0], name[1], street[2]]);
            });  
        });
    }
});
```

But it's not working. I am searching for a solution for 4 days now, so you are my last chance to get this job done.

Comment: thx to Abbas & PeeHaa for editing :)

Comment: solved..  think I need glasses

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", url: "xml/pois_small.xml", dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('sixcms_article').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).find('field[container$="content"]').text();
            var name = $(this).find('title').text();
            var street = $(this).find('field[name$="street"]').text();
            DEMODB.transaction(function (transaction) {
                transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO page(id, name, street) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [id[0], name[1], street[2]]);
            });  
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between this code and the one in the question?